# My function works, but when I run it R crashes

Tags: r

I try to look for instances that are missed in parallel processing. The code checks whether the csv file is missing and IF that's the case it will go and create a transformed (2D) version of the instance based on other .csv files (untransformed version of data). I tried to do this with standard for loop + if statement. But my program keeps crashing. I am getting the following image. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ICal.png)

(1) Here is my code which uses foreach to get to this solution:

```
ConfirmAllFilesExist <- function(i){
  setwd("C:/Users/x/Desktop/Coswara/Extracted_data/")
  library(nonlinearTseries)
  library(crqa)
  library(Rcpp)
  library(parallelly)
  library(tseriesChaos)
  library(foreach)
  library(doParallel)
  library(future)
  library(doFuture)
  library(snow)
  library(doSNOW)
  if (file.exists(paste0('2D-cough-heavy-',as.character(i),'.csv'))  == FALSE) {
    print(as.character(i))
    data <- read.csv(paste0('cough-heavy-',as.character(i),'.csv'))
    data <- as.numeric(unlist(data))
    tau.ami <- timeLag(data, technique = "ami", lag.max = 100, do.plot = F)
    emb.dim = estimateEmbeddingDim(data, time.lag = tau.ami, max.embedding.dim = 15, do.plot = F)
    Takens <- buildTakens(data, emb.dim, tau.ami)
    paste0('Completed embedding unit: ',as.character(i))
    x <- Takens[,1]
    y <- Takens[,2]
    z <- Takens[,3]
    #u <- (1/3) * (x + y + z)
    v <- (1/sqrt(6)) * (x + y - 2*z)
    w <- (1/sqrt(2)) * (x - y)
    file <- data.frame(v, w)
    # save file
    write.csv(file, paste0('2D-cough-heavy-',as.character(i),'.csv'), row.names = FALSE)
    print(paste0('File ',as.character(i),'has been added.'))
  }
} 

foreach(i = 0:2016) %dopar% ConfirmAllFilesExist(i)
stopCluster(cl)
```

(2) standard for + if function which gives me the same result. The aim is to get this one to work but R keeps crashing. Anyone who knows what is happening here?

```
setwd("C:/Users/x/Desktop/Coswara/Extracted_data/")
library(parallelly)
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
library(future)
library(doFuture)
library(snow)
library(doSNOW)
library(nonlinearTseries)
library(tseriesChaos)

# Confirm whether all files specified have been created in parallel processing.
ConfirmAllFilesExist <- function(start,stop){
  setwd("C:/Users/x/Desktop/Coswara/Extracted_data/")
  library(nonlinearTseries)
  library(crqa)
  library(Rcpp)
  library(parallelly)
  library(tseriesChaos)
  library(foreach)
  library(doParallel)
  library(future)
  library(doFuture)
  library(snow)
  library(doSNOW)
  for (i in start:stop) {
    if (file.exists(paste0('C:/Users/x/Desktop/Coswara/Extracted_data/2D-cough-heavy-',as.character(i),'.csv'))  == FALSE) {
      print(as.character(i))
      data <- read.csv(paste0('cough-heavy-',as.character(i),'.csv'))
      print('two')
      data <- as.numeric(unlist(data))
      print('two')
      tau.ami <- timeLag(data, technique = "ami", lag.max = 100, do.plot = FALSE)
      print('two')
      emb.dim <- estimateEmbeddingDim(data, time.lag = tau.ami, max.embedding.dim = 15, do.plot = FALSE)
      print('two')
      Takens <- buildTakens(data, emb.dim, tau.ami)
      print(paste0('Completed embedding unit: ',as.character(i)))
      x <- Takens[,1]
      y <- Takens[,2]
      z <- Takens[,3]
      #u <- (1/3) * (x + y + z)
      v <- (1/sqrt(6)) * (x + y - 2*z)
      w <- (1/sqrt(2)) * (x - y)
      file <- data.frame(v, w)
      # save file
    write.csv(file, paste0('2D-cough-heavy-',as.character(i),'.csv'), row.names = FALSE)
    print(paste0('File ',as.character(i),'has been added.'))
    }
  }
  
} 
ConfirmAllFilesExist(0,2016)
```

Comment: from the print statements you know which file causes the crash. Could you use dput to show us the head of that data?

Comment: Please try to reduce the problem to just what is relevant for us. For starters, this means removing all of the `library(.)` calls that are not required to reproduce the issue (e.g., `Rcpp`, `foreach`, `future`, `doFuture`, `snow`, `doSNOW`, perhaps `parallelly`). The next step is to give us something to work with, i.e., ***sample data***, as Jagge already requested. For good discussions on reproducible questions, please see https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info. Thank you!